# why preserving norm is equivalent to preserving inner product in rigid body transformation

Tags: linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry, rigid-transformation

Define rigid body motion as following transformation $g$
$$g:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$$
such that
$$|g(v)|=|v|,\forall v \in \mathbb R^3$$
$$g(u) \times g(v) = g(u\times v)$$
according to [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity):
$\langle u,v\rangle=\frac{1}{4}(|u+v|^2-|u-v|^2)$. Inner product preservation(i.e. $\langle u,v\rangle=\langle g(u),g(v)\rangle$) can be derived while I'm stuck in reaching it. Here is my deduction:
\begin{align}
\langle u,v\rangle &=\frac{1}{4}(|u+v|^2-|u-v|^2) \\
    &=\frac{1}{4}(|g(u+v)|^2-|g(u-v)|^2)
\end{align}
**if $|g(u+v)|=|g(u)+g(v)|$ and $|g(u-v)|=|g(u)-g(v)|$**, I can easily arrive at $\langle u,v\rangle=\langle g(u),g(v)\rangle$. However, above two conditions are not obvious to me just in a purely algebraic view. Of course, it is otherwise obvious to me in a geometrical view:[image]
So who can help proving this in a purely algebraic view?

This problem comes from [Multiple View Geomotry - Lecture 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khLM8VV8LuM&index=4&list=PLTBdjV_4f-EJn6udZ34tht9EVIW7lbeo4&t=9s), in **rigid body motion** session. Here is the [slide](https://vision.in.tum.de/teaching/ss2016/mvg2016/material)(password:mvg-ss16).

Comment: I am watching exactly the same lecture and I have exactly the same question! :-)

Comment: According to the lecturer, the polarization identity can be used for the proof, isn't it like that? But both answers to this question do *not* make use of it. So is there a simpler proof?

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of the **[Theorem of Mazur-Ulam](http://www.helsinki.fi/~jvaisala/mazurulam.pdf)**: *Every bijective isometry $f: E \to F$ between normed spaces is affine.*

You have in the link I provided a proof of Mazur-Ulam theorem. In your case (rigit body motion), $g$ is indeed bijective.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to show it without using the Mazur-Ulam theorem:

$v = V - 0$

$u = U - 0$

$g_*(v) = g(V) - g(0)$

1. Using the rigid-body motion property $||g_*(x)|| = ||x||$ we have:

$||g_*(-v)|| = ||-v|| = ||v|| = ||g_*(v)|| = ||-g_*(v)||$

2. Using the rigid-body motion property $||X - Y|| = ||g(X) - g(Y)||$ we have:

$||-g_*(-v) + g_*(v)|| = ||-(g(-V) - g(0)) + (g(V) - g(0))|| = ||g(V) - g(-V)|| = ||V - (-V)|| = 2||v||$

1 + 2 imply:

$g_*(-v) = -g_*(v)$

Then:

$||u + v|| = ||(U - 0) + (V - 0)|| = ||U - (-V)|| = ||g(U) - g(-V)|| = ||(g(U) - g(0)) - (g(-V) - g(0))|| = ||g_*(u) - g_*(-v)|| = ||g_*(u) + g_*(v)||$

Also with the rigid-body motion property $||g_*(x)|| = ||x||$ we have:

$\sqrt{||g_*(u)||^2 + ||g_*(v)||^2 + 2<u, v>} = \sqrt{||u||^2 + ||v||^2 + 2<u, v>} = ||u + v|| = ||g_*(u) + g_*(v)|| = \sqrt{||g_*(u)||^2 + ||g_*(v)||^2 + 2<g_*(u), g_*(v)>}$

That implies:
$<u, v> = <g_*(u), g_*(v)>$

Answer (score 0):

The lecturer has made a mistake. He required that a rigid-body motion preserves the norm:

$ |g(v)|=|v|$

But this does **not** imply that the inner product is preserved. A counterexample is a function $f$ defined as
$f(z)=z$ if $|z|≠1$ and $f(z)=−z$ if $|z|=1$. This function preserves norm but not inner product (see comment to this question: [Does a transformation that preserves origin and norm also preserve inner product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3226881/991419)).

This is the reason why it is so hard to show that the preservation of norm implies the preservation of the inner product - simply because it is wrong!

Instead of requiring preservation of **norm**, the lecturer should have required preservation of **distances**. Rigid-body motions are isometries:

$|g (u) − g (v )| = |u -v|, \forall u,v \in \mathbb R^3$

With this definition, the preservation of the inner product can be shown algebraically.