# Does a transformation that preserves origin and norm also preserve inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$

Assuming that $f$ preserves both norm and origin, is it possible to prove that $f$ also preserves inner product?

I've been able to prove it by assuming that $f$ also preserves either angles —and by that I mean $\frac{<u,v>}{||u||\;||v||}=\frac{<fu,fv>}{||fu||\;||fv||}$

or euclidean metric —and by that I mean $||u-v||=||fu-fv||$.

But I want to know if it is possible —and in case it is then also how— to prove that without any further assumptions other than the preservation of norm and origin.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law), formulas 2 and 4.

Comment: You don't need to additionally require that $f$ preserves origin, as $\|f0\| = 0$ from norm preservation, so $f0 = 0$

Comment: @logarithm
I set both formulas equal and I got this $||x-y||^2+||x+y||^2=2(||x||^2+||y||^2)$

Then, I set $x=u,\;y=v$ and —by considering preservation of the norm— I get $<f(u-v),f(u-v)>+<f(u+v),f(u+v)>=2(<fu,fu>+<fv,fv>)$

This seems to prove that $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$. Did I get it right?

Comment: No if you don't assume $f$ to be linear. For a simple counterexample, let $f(z)=z$ if $\lVert z\rVert \not= 1$ and $f(z)=-z$ if $\lVert z\rVert = 1$. This $f$ maps the origin to itself and preserves norm but not inner product.